# How to replace values in netcdf file with Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using a NASA GISS netcdf file with gridded monthly temperature values. According to the [readme file](https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.gistemp.html) "Missing data is flagged with a value of 9999.f" I am trying to plot the data but keep getting blank maps. I think its because this 9999.f value is throwing off my scale. How do I replace it with Nan? I tried:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data2 = Dataset(r'GriddedAir250.nc')

lats=data2.variables['lat'][:]
lons=data2.variables['lon'][:]
time=data2.variables['time'][:]
air=data2.variables['air'][:]

air=air.astype('float')
air[air==9999]=np.nan
```

But it looks like this gives me an array of boolean values:
[image]

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What library are you using to read the file?  Don't make us guess; include all the relevant `import` statements that you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I just went back and added my import statements to the question

Answer (score 0):

`netCDF4` creates [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html), and automatically masks the value 9999.0. In your code, this means the result of `air = data2.variables['air'][:]` is a masked array.  So I suspect the problem is that the plotting code that you are trying to use does not handle masked arrays.  If you think the plotting code can handle `nan`, you could try

```
air = air.filled(fill_value=np.nan)
```

This will convert `air` to a regular NumPy array, with the masked values (i.e. the values that were originaly 9999.0 in the .nc file) converted to `nan`.